# Изменение значений в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть некий DataFrame, представленный ниже:

```
     name   version  year
  0  Python 2      1999
  1  Java   SE8    2010
  2  PHP    8      2015
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как в DataFrame, который представлен выше изменить значения на те, что представлены в таблице ниже?
Т.е первый столбец новых данных - это заголовки столбцов где происходят изменения, а второй столбец значения, которые изменяются
Таблица с новыми данными может изменяться, но общий вид остается такой же

```
0 year 2000
1 year 2014
2 version 7
```

Должно получится так ↓

```
     name   version year
  0  Python 2       2000
  1  Java   SE8     2014
  2  PHP    7       2015
```

Comment: `df.loc[0, 'year'] = 2000` и т.д.

Comment: А если таблица с новыми значениями будет меняться?
Но общий вид ее такой же будет

Comment: Ну пройдите про ней циклом. Как сделать "векторно" я что-то не соображу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в общем случае решения можно свести к циклу по совету @CrazyElf:

```
for i in df2.itertuples():
    df1.loc[i[0], i[1]] = i[2]
```

df1:

```
     name version  year
0  Python       2  2008
1    Java     SE8  2014
2     PHP       7  2015
```

**UPDATE**

Вот что-то такое, более-менее векторное:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df2,prefix='', prefix_sep='', dtype=bool)
t = dummies.multiply(dummies[1], axis=0).drop(columns=[1]).replace(0, np.nan)
df1.update(t.fillna(df1))
```

df1, понятно, будет

```
     name version    year
0  Python       2  2008.0
1    Java     SE8  2014.0
2     PHP     7.0    2015
```

Comment: Тогда уж распаковать `for idx,col,val in ...`, числовые индексы выглядят некрасиво )

Comment: пускай товарищ сам додумает, раз он не представил название колонок для второго датафрейма. меня больше интересует возможность векторного решения.

Comment: Сделал по итогу циклом, строки, которые подаются на вход "сплитанул" на списки и  df.loc[int(i[0]),i[1]] = i[2]

Answer (score 1):

мне на ум пришел такой вариант, правда с побочным эффектом:

```
>>> df2  # обозвал колонки
'''
       col   val
0     year  2000
1     year  2014
2  version     7
'''
df1.year = df2.query('col=="year"').val.combine_first(df1.year)
df1.version = df2.query('col=="version"').val.combine_first(df1.version)
```

или, чтобы не повторяться, можно циклом пройтись:

```
for c in df2.col.unique():
    df1[c] = df2.query('col==@c').val.combine_first(df1[c])

>>> df1
'''
     name version    year
0  Python       2  2000.0
1    Java     SE8  2014.0
2     PHP     7.0  2015.0
```